# Recording sound in matlab but telling the diff of 2 acoustic signals by frequency

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I'm doing a project and trying to have a sound record 2 sounds consecutively and be able to read them both but be able to determine which signal is playing at the higher frequency. Is this possible in matlab or would I have to determine the difference in another way.

Comment: You should ask this on dsp.stackexchange or else at least describe your algorithm for discerning the two signals. Are you recording with one microphone or two? If the sounds are in completely different frequencies then you should be able to do it with simple filtering

Comment: I am just going to make an assumption that your 2 sources are speakers playing single tones. If both sources start at the exact same time and are at the exact same amplitudes, you are probably going to have some trouble determining which speaker is producing the higher frequency. One thing you could do is predetermine some characteristic of one of the speakers, such as speaker 1 has double the amplitude of speaker 2. Or it has some other special pattern/configuration. Basically we need some more information about your exact problems before suggestions can be made accurately.

Comment: Dan - yes I will be using one central node/latop to play a tone and will have a second node/laptop to record and read the sound and be able to say this node is on the left or right. So trying to figure out the best way to distinguish between the two tones. I want to have a tone set for left and one set for the right. I want the sound to have 400 Samples at 44100 for 10ms between 18-22freq just outside the human hearing range so that the sound is not annoying etc.

Comment: MZimmerman6 - i thought about playing the two tones at diff sample rates so one plays faster than the other but having trouble with the code now because I really don't code in matlab and when I did it was for image processing. I'm just doing this for a final project for school so I can graduate. So to both any help with code or sample code is greatly appreciated because I am confused as hell.